# Gunicorn gives ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH when running without Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi, gunicorn, http-content-length

I'm hosting a [Flask built](http://flask.pocoo.org) website with Gunicorn and Nginx through [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), which works perfectly well. In my `supervisord.conf` file I run gunicorn as follows:

```
command=/home/beta/imd/venv/bin/gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -b 127.0.0.1:5000 -w 1 app:app
```

I now tried running Gunicorn directly without Nginx in front of it using the following command (to include logging)

```
sudo /home/beta/imd/venv/bin/gunicorn \
    --worker-class eventlet \
    -b 0.0.0.0:80 \
    -w 1 \
    --access-logfile /home/beta/gunicorn_access.log \
    --error-logfile /home/beta/gunicorn_error.log \
    app:app
```

but when opening a webpage, two of the 20 requests the page consists of (an image and Twitter Bootstrap css file) give an `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`. 
I checked out the gunicorn logs, but in there nothing strange seems to happen. I get no error and the access logs report regular `200` status codes.
I get the error in Chrome, Opera and Safari, but not in Firefox.

I find it so strange that it doesn't happen when also using Nginx, which suggests that Nginx adjusts the `content-length` headers.

Does anybody know what could cause this problem?

Comment: This is likely caused by a caching issue. Nginx retrieves the correct cached version of the content but gunicorn doesn't,  which results in the error

Comment: I experience the same error. I can 'solve' it by removing '--worker-class eventlet' from the command (but this is not what I want).

Comment: It might mean your disk is full, make sure it has free space.